# Using \input in \title with amsart affects case

Tags: input, amsart

I have a bunch of documents that should all have a common string in their title, so I wanted to move that string into a separate file and include it using `\input`.  That way if I want to change the string, I only have to change it in one place.  However, when using the `amsart` class, I found that doing so affects the way the title is typeset; specifically, the case.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\title{ This is a title: \input{catchy} }
\author{Frank Foobar}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
Lorem ipsum dolor.
\end{document}
```

The file `catchy.tex` contains a single line:

```
Some catchy phrase
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Note that the catchy phrase is in mixed case, whereas the `amsart` package normally sets the title in all caps.   If I actually include the literal text and change the `\title` command to

```
\title{ This is a title: Some catchy phrase }
```

then I get what I wanted:

[image]

How can I keep using `\input` and get the desired all-caps output?

It seems somehow as though the upper-case conversion is done before expanding the `\input`.

Comment: The code for uppercasing doesn't expand its argument before doing the actual conversion. Probably the only way out is to use the _primitive_ `\input` (in LaTeX, `\@@input`) and an `\edef` trick. Something like: `\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\title{This is a title: \@@input catchy }}\x`.

Comment: Interestingly, when I run the MWE, I get the error `! LaTeX Error: File 'CATCHY.tex' not found.` (I'm on Linux which is case sensitive for file names). So the upper casing is applied before the `\input` is called.

Comment: Of course a simple workaround is to re-apply upper casing in your input file (`\MakeUppercase{Some catchy phrase}`), but I guess this is not what you want?

Comment: @Marijn: The `CATCHY.tex` error is peculiar.  I am also on Linux and I do not get that error.  I have `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian)`.

Comment: @Marijn: The `\MakeUppercase` workaround is helpful, thanks!  It'd be a problem if I wanted to `\input` the catchy phrase in some other context than the title, or if I wanted to be able to use it in titles for different document classes, but I think that will accomplish what I want for now.